# Replace all image sources that are local with PHP

Tags: php

I need to replace all of the image sources on my website from `<img src="images/etc.png" />` to have `bloginfo('template_url')` in front of them.

I know I can do this manually but just for convenience I would like PHP to do this itself. I know it can be done, I tried with str_replace but I just can't figure it out. I'm not a PHP whiz!

Thanks to anyone who can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this applies to all URIs in the page (links included), you could simply use the [HTML base tag](http://w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp).

If not, `str_replace()` might suffice instead of using regular expressions.

```
$html = '<html>...</html>';
$html = str_replace('<img src="', '<img src="' . bloginfo('template_url'), $html);
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to do, but for some reason it's not working. It's not changing the URLs at all. Quite strange, but it could have something to do with WordPress' framework..

Comment: According to the WordPress docs on `bloginfo()`, it "always prints a result to the browser. If you need the values for use in PHP, use `get_bloginfo()`."
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo
Maybe that's the problem.

Comment: I tried that as well, no luck. I'm pretty confused as to why it doesn't work but I wouldn't know where to start if I wanted to look for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a program such as NetBeans or Eclipse you could import the folder into a project and doing a find/replace with some Regex to switch them up. That was the actual source code will be changed.

Comment: even some of the more basic text/code editors, like notepad++ have a find&replace in files options.

Comment: I'm not really looking to do it that way though. I work on multiple WordPress blogs daily and just thought it would save time to just pop in a little function that will do the copy&paste for me since I do the XHTML/CSS first, then implement WP.